# Error when using the clo() function in the compositions library

Tags: closures

I am getting the following error, when I want to use the clo function in the compositions library:
Constrained linear ordination is fitted with the function 'rrvglm'

Examples (from the help package):

> (tmp <- clo(c(1,2,3)))
> Error in clo(c(1, 2, 3)) :
> Constrained linear ordination is fitted with the function 'rrvglm'

> data(Hydrochem)
> plot( clo(Hydrochem,8:9) )
> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': Constrained linear ordination is fitted with the function 'rrvglm'

Any ideas?
Thanks

I am coming across an error when running a function and I expect to get advice as to whether I need to update anything, or that there is a bug in the library, etc.